# Get AD Password Complexity remotely .Net Core

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-core, ldap, asp.net-core-2.0

I am looking a way to get the configuration of AD password Complexity using .Net Core.

I have the admin credentials of the LDAP server.
So far I used `Novell.Directory.Ldap` In order to verify any user login credentials, didn't see there something relate to AD password Complexity.

Is there something you know I can use for .Net Core?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know AD has a single fixed ruleset that defines a "complex" password that's either on or off rather than there being any kind of grade for how complex a given password is.

In which case this is well documented and you'd just have to write a validator that checks for the same rules AD uses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements

If you need to check specific GPO values, you can make a WMI query once you know the GPO object ID:

`Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\rsop\computer -Query "select * from rsop_securitysettings" | where {$_.gpoid -like '*{Insert GPO ID here}*'}`

Comment: The problem is that there is a minimum length I need to know, that is configurable.

Comment: You can use WMI to query GPO settings. I've updated my answer.